# How do I view images from pdf in pdfminer3

Tags: python, pdfminer

Here is my code.

```
from pdfminer3.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer3.pdfpage import PDFPage
from pdfminer3.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager
from pdfminer3.pdfinterp import PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer3.converter import PDFPageAggregator
from pdfminer3.converter import TextConverter
import io

resource_manager = PDFResourceManager()
fake_file_handle = io.StringIO()
converter = TextConverter(resource_manager, fake_file_handle,laparams=LAParams())
page_interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(resource_manager, converter)

with open('/storage/emulated/0/Download/Rick-Riordan-The-Tyrants-Tomb-The-Trials-of-Apollo-4.pdf','rb') as fh:

    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fh,
                                  caching=True,
                                  check_extractable=True):
        page_interpreter.process_page(page)

    text = fake_file_handle.getvalue()

# close open handles
converter.close()
fake_file_handle.close()

print(text)
```

I just want to see the image. My version is python 3. I don't want to have to import another module, so please try to give solution that uses pdfminer3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify in Text Converter where to save images from pdf. Try adding ImageWriter..

```
pdfResourceManager = PDFResourceManager()
convertedText = StringIO()
layoutParams = LAParams()
imageWriter = ImageWriter('pathToSaveImages/..')
converter = TextConverter(pdfResourceManager, convertedText, codec='utf-8',laparams=layoutParams, imagewriter=imageWriter)
```